# Play Animation Too Slow when parenting (Keep Transform)

Tags: animation, 3d-view, parent, performance

I have created a simple mess with a simple UV sphere and have used the arrays and curve modifiers around a bezier circle to surround the UV sphere with spikes. the spikes are simple circles extruded.

All works fine in terms on animation, quite fast until I apply the *Set Parent to > Object (keep transform)*. Once I do this, the parenting, whenever I play an animation, after adding some keyframes, the laptop lags massively and it takes 10secs to move from frame to frame. It has never happened before, I have created some clips, and have realized it is if all is parented. If I keep the sphere without being parented to the spikes, it all works nicely.

Can anybody help me fixing this?

Comment: pls provide blend file because we have no idea (except your very rough explanation) of what you made. thx.

Comment: Hello, HiAll, welcome. I think you'll have to share a .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ for this to be answerable.. there are too many variables to guess at.